# How to add @progress/kendo-scrollview package in Angular 4 project

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to add `'@progress/kendo-scrollview'` package in the project. I'm getting the following error

> Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404) loading
>   https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview/dist/cdn/js/kendo-angular-scrollview.js
>   Error: XHR error (404) loading
>   https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview/dist/cdn/js/kendo-angular-scrollview.js
>         at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1166:39)
>         at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:31)
>         at Zone.runTask (https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:47)
>         at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:496:34)
>         at invokeTask (https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1517:14)
>         at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1554:21)
>     Error loading
>   https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview/dist/cdn/js/kendo-angular-scrollview.js
>   as "@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview" from
>   https://127.0.0.1:470/src/app/app.module.js
>         at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1166:39)
>         at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:31)
>         at Zone.runTask (https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:47)
>         at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:496:34)
>         at invokeTask (https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1517:14)
>         at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1554:21)
>     Error loading
>   https://127.0.0.1:470/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview/dist/cdn/js/kendo-angular-scrollview.js
>   as "@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview" from
>   https://127.0.0.1:470/src/app/app.module.js

I have done following steps to add '@progress/kendo-scrollview'

```
- installed the package 
    npm install --save@progress/kendo-scrollview
- Added to package.json file
     @progress/kendo-angular-scrollview": "2.0.0
- Added in system.js file
    '@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview/dist/cdn/js/kendo-angular-scrollview.js'
- imported in App.module
    import { ScrollViewModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview';
    @NGModule
    imports:[scrollviewModule]
```

is there any step missing, 
Thank you

Comment: try ```npm i``` .

Comment: no, still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the following steps and it worked.

- Go to your project root folder and open command prompt.
- type 'npm i @progress/kendo-angular-scrollview'
- add its dependencies.
- the package folder should get added to your node_modules

follow the link for details https://www.npmjs.com/package/@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview